Setting Schema registry for standalone kafka and zookeper
I have already setup kafka with zookeper in my local of server and running in their default ports. But i want to use schema registry feature and do like to use confluents schema registry on docker and using that with my local kafka on server so i have composed docker-compose file but it is failing.
Here is my docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.0.1
    ports:
      - 8181:8181
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=PLAINTEXT://host.docker.internal:9092 
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8081
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS=GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN=*
  schema-registry-ui:
    image: landoop/schema-registry-ui
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - SCHEMAREGISTRY_URL=http://localhost:8081  
      - PROXY=true

Kindly tell me error or what should i use

You're making the UI container connect to itself, by the way, and Kafka doesn't need Zookeeper anymore
